# RVM + Ruby 1.9.3 + MacPorts Typhoeus Missing > Bundle Install stuck at FFI

Tags: ruby, wordpress, rvm, macports

I have Ruby version manager RVM on OSC Mavericks with MacPorts. I was trying to update WPScan that runs on ruby. I was trying to do an update:

ruby wpscan.rb --update
when I run into this error:
Could not find gem 'typhoeus (>= 0.6.3) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
I had this error before. So a ran bundle install. Then I ran into other errors:

```
sudo bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Installing ffi (1.9.3) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/jasper/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for ffi_call() in -lffi... yes
-----------------cut ----------------
checking for ffi_prep_cif_var()... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

make
compiling AbstractMemory.c
compiling ArrayType.c
compiling Buffer.c
compiling Call.c
Call.c:303:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'rb_thread_call_without_gvl' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    rbffi_thread_blocking_region(call_blocking_function, data, (void *) -1, NULL);
    ^
./Thread.h:78:39: note: expanded from macro 'rbffi_thread_blocking_region'
# define rbffi_thread_blocking_region rb_thread_call_without_gvl
                                      ^
1 warning generated.
compiling ClosurePool.c
compiling DataConverter.c
compiling DynamicLibrary.c
compiling ffi.c
compiling Function.c
Function.c:479:33: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'VALUE (void *)' to parameter of type 'void *(*)(void *)' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        rb_thread_call_with_gvl(callback_with_gvl, &cb);
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Function.c:102:46: note: passing argument to parameter 'func' here
extern void *rb_thread_call_with_gvl(void *(*func)(void *), void *data1);
                                             ^
Function.c:563:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'rb_thread_call_without_gvl' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        rb_thread_call_without_gvl(async_cb_wait, &w, async_cb_stop, &w);
        ^
Function.c:738:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
3 warnings generated.
compiling FunctionInfo.c
compiling LastError.c
compiling LongDouble.c
compiling MappedType.c
compiling MemoryPointer.c
compiling MethodHandle.c
compiling Platform.c
compiling Pointer.c
compiling Struct.c
compiling StructByReference.c
compiling StructByValue.c
compiling StructLayout.c
compiling Thread.c
compiling Type.c
compiling Types.c
compiling Variadic.c
linking shared-object ffi_c.bundle

make install
make: /opt/local/bin/gmkdir: No such file or directory
make: [/Users/jasper/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.3/lib/ffi_c.bundle] Error 1 (ignored)
/opt/local/bin/ginstall -c -m 0755 ffi_c.bundle /Users/jasper/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.3/lib
make: /opt/local/bin/ginstall: No such file or directory
make: *** [/Users/jasper/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.3/lib/ffi_c.bundle] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/jasper/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/jasper/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.3/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.9.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I do have /opt/local/bin/gmdir. I added it myself, but the error remains and then there are some warnings and errors concerning other directories that not seem to exist. why does the script does not create them? Any easy way around these errors so I can ran my favourite WP scanner?

NB I thought RVM would work without MacPorts... But it is looking for directories in MacPorts.

Answer (score 0):

`gmkdir` is a part of GNU Core Utilities.

You can install them with command `sudo port install coreutils`.